Zero derivative not necessarily implies function being constant
Let $D\subseteq\mathbb{C}$ and let $f:D\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ be a function. Suppose that $f$ has zero derivative everywhere on $D$. Is $f$ constant on $D$?
It is well-known that if $D$ is open and connected, then $f$ would be constant on $D$. This easily comes from $D$ being polygonally connected and the application of Cauchy-Riemann condition.
However, if the openness is dropped, then $f$ is not necessarily constant on $D$. This is shown in this paper.
My question is, would $f$ being constant recover if $D$ is assumed to be path-connected? I have seen people casually mentioned that it is also NOT necessarily true but they didn't provide any reference. (References will be greatly appreciated!) If that's indeed the case, what about the path being $C^1$?

I might be wrong, but the first paragraph of the paper you linked seems to contradict you. They give a counterexample where $D$ is an arc (path connected).

@LoganPost You are right. I should be more clearer. What I am thinking is some nicer paths. The path in the paper is not rectifiable. I actually saw people mentioned about using fractal path like Koch Snowflake to give a counterexample. That's why I'm asking about what if the paths are less pathological like $C^1$ or something.

If the path is given by a differentiable $t\to \gamma(t)$ and $f$ is also differentiable on the path then $t\to g(t)=\Re f\circ \gamma(t)$ is differentiable as a real variable function on an interval and same with $h(t)=\Im f\circ \gamma(t)$; then $(g+ih)'(t)=0$ as the chain rule still works so $g'=h'=0$ so $g,h$ constant hence $f$ is too on the curve
